# Bootstrap - Rows span columns but stay responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a bootstrap based timetable, and I want it to be responsive across devices but it's a little harder than I though.

On larger devices, the layout should be the following with 3 parallel sessions, but the hour slots align with each other across columns:

[image: Larger view]

This will differ from the mobile view where the columns sit below each other and the horizontal alignment is ignored:

[image: Mobile View]

I did try to use a table in each column but quickly realise that idea was flawed. Various other attempts to make the columns the same height have also failed.

The bigger problem is that the content for each cell can vary, massively.

Comment: Do you need to be able to show the entirety of the content in each cell? With a fixed height you could accomplish the stacking by nesting each day within a .col-lg-4 so they would stack on a smaller that lg viewport

Comment: would be nice you share your code with us.

Comment: Well, I think the first practical problem you're going to run into is Bootstrap's grid is neither divisible by 5 nor 7 (assuming num calendar days per week), unless you visit the customize build page - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: @freestock.tk i've no useful code to provide, they were all total dead ends, I have included the two simple ideas I initially had

Comment: @ThisClark the number of columns can differ, and I am aware of the restrictions that I would have to put in place

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried nesting columns? You could put a single row of three columns, and then nest other divs inside of those columns. [Here's a Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8NO8iQPChU). You can see that the columns stack in mobile. Here's the code, it's relatively straightforward:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-top"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-left"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-left"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-left"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-top"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-mid"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-mid"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-mid"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-top"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-right"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-right"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-right"></div>

      </div> 
    </div>


</div>
```

UPDATED to accommodate the white blocks. In a large display you can see that I've just used CSS to make the empty blocks white, and when you view it in mobile, those blocks are hidden. [Here's the updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/SplkxXYLBk#), and here's the code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-top"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-left"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-mid visible-lg" id="white"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-left"></div>    
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">   
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-top"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-mid visible-lg" id="white"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-mid"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-mid visible-lg" id="white"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-top"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-topright"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-bottomright"></div>
      </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem with this is it doesn't account for the white spaces where presumably there are no calendar events to fill.

Comment: As @ThisClark pointed out, your example wouldn't be able to handle the white space

Comment: I've edited my original post. I used the `visible` class to make the white blocks only visible in the browser. Is this more in line of what you're looking for?